# Git --min-children, any way?

Tags: git, git-rev-list

Is there any clean way to obtain the effect of an hypothetical `--min-children=` git rev-list parameter? (which would of course be the counterpart of `--min-parents`, returning the commits that have the indicated minimum number of children)

The only way I can see is to parse the result of `rev-list --children` to pick the rows with (number of columns)=(min-children wanted + 1), but I wonder if there's a better way (and why git doesn't natively support such a search).

I think this might be useful in the quest to find the commits belonging to a single feature branch, but it would be a nice think to have in general.

Comment: could you explain what your hypothetical option does?

Comment: maybe, also explain why you want something like that.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ I edited the question to clarify both points

Comment: Yes, ok, but draw a graph; as soon as your feature branch gets merged into the master branch again, every commit in the feature branch will have all the later commits in the master branch; maybe I'm a bit too confused, but I don't see how you could tell two branches apart by that

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ I'm not sure I understood your point, more precisely this _could_ help to find the **start** of the branch. Of course I'm referring to a situation where the branch was not merged with a fast-forward. I haven't yet thought out if it would work in all situations.

Comment: aaah, you're looking for the first commit that has two children, iterating up (towards the graph root)?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ well, more or less. Actually the right one would probably be the last one for which one of the children is the branch from which the feature branch originated. This should handle both the cases of multiple merges and of sub-branches on the feature branch.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺOf course this leaves you with having to know from which branch the feature branch started, but I don't think we can do any better with this smart no-start-point-metadata model.